# Behavior in node 0.8.15 and node 0.10.26 - (Can't set headers after they are sent)

Tags: node.js

I was using Web Application which uses nodejs as backend Web Server, It was running fine as long as I was using node version 0.8.X, when I switched to recent node version 0.10.26, then the app is throwing error in below:

```
     res.redirect('/path/to/page')
```

node_modules/redis/index.js:523
            throw err;
                  ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:691:11)

Can you please let me know why this throws error in 0.10.26?

With regards,
-M-

Answer (score 0):

This is because you sent 2 times header Example

```
res.send("foo");
res.send("bar");
```

You can debug this like that:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.on('header', function() {
    console.trace('HEADERS GOING TO BE WRITTEN');
  });
  next();
});
```

Comment: My doubt is if in case 2 times header sent, then in node version 0.8.X also it should have thrown error, but with node 0.8.X it works perfectly without any issues any time, so I am thinking what happened to 0.10.26, why the issue is exposed in 0.10.26, but not in 0.8.X, is there any behavioral change in this version?

Comment: I think you should debug this to know more.